# Domain alias in xampp

Tags: apache, laravel, xampp, alias

I'm trying to place a domain alias named `noetic.dev`, I'm having a fresh `laravel` installation in the htdocs folder named `noetic`.

For achieving this I tried to change `httpd.conf` file and added this:

```
Alias /noetic.dev "F:/xamp/htdocs/Noetic/public/" 

<Directory "F:/xamp/htdocs/Noetic/public/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Require local
</Directory>
```

and I changed following in `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
    ServerName noetic.dev
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/NitsEdit/public
</VirtualHost>
```

and similarly I've in the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       noetic.dev
```

Now while trying the link to be as `http://localhost:8082/noetic.dev/` I'm getting the result but while trying noetic.dev:8082 I'm getting an error

> Access forbidden:
>   You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

I don't know where I'm doing wrong, guide me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Vhost you have wrong path of C:/

```
DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/NitsEdit/public
```

that should be

```
 DocumentRoot F:/xamp/htdocs/Noetic/public/
```